# Has anyone replaced a macbook screen?

Tags: macos, macbook

I cracked the screen on my black [macbook](http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/apple-macbook-core-2/1707-3121_7-32453657.html).  I am under warranty (3 year extended) but I know they won't replace it for cheap.  Has anyone replaced a macbook lcd before?  Anyone know where to get a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScreenTek will sell you a [MacBook LCD Screen](http://www.screentekinc.com/Apple__MacBook-family-notebooks-lcd-screens.shtml) (their [removal instructions are here](http://www.screentekinc.com/lcd-removal-instructions_en,macbook.shtml)) or you can ship them your laptop and have them replace it for you. They had the best pricing the last time I shopped around.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite site for this is [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/). I had an LCD problem that required me to take the screen off, their tools and guides were the best I could possibly hope for. I ended up not needing the LVDS replacement cable I initially ordered and they were very nice about taking it back.